# How to send an xml document created using JDOM api to a client?

Tags: xml, jsp, jdom

I want to send an xml document that i have created using jdom api. I send it to the client side in a jsp page by using out as an outputstream.

Here is some part of my code that i wrote in a jsp page -

```
<%
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = builder.build(new File("D:\\out.xml"));
XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
Format format = outputter.getFormat();
format.setOmitDeclaration(true);
outputter.output(out, doc);
%>
```

but i am getting an error at client side where i am using following code in a java file -

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = builder.build(connection.getInputStream());
```

*here connection is an object of HttpURLConnection class.

error is as--

org.jdom.inpput.JDOMParseException: error on line 22: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often the cause is a malformed XML file, with a common problem being a blank line accidentally inserted before the required first line of the xml:

```
[ A blank line here will cause the error ]
<?xml version-"1.0"?>
```